# Delicious API replies with "access denied"

Tags: access-denied, delicious-api

I'm trying to access all posts from delicious, according to [delicious API](http://delicious.com/help/api#posts_all). In Ubuntu Linux i give the command:

```
curl https://myusername:mypassword@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/all
```

where myusername and mypassword are registered with an yahoo mail account. I get the answer:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<result code="access denied" />
<!-- fe07.feeds.del.ac4.yahoo.net uncompressed/chunked Mon Nov  9 13:06:28 PST 2009 -->
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you're registered with a Yahoo! ID, you need to use OAuth rather than basic authentication.

Unfortunately, using command-line tools like this is considerably harder with OAuth. Last I checked there wasn't a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the status code you get? Code 999? If so, that's Yahoo's default status code for throttling your requests, i.e. you're trying to pull your posts too often. I've noticed that if you make the /posts/all call too often (more than once every few minutes), you'll get throttled.

If you don't *need* to get ALL of your posts, you should try using the [/v1/posts/recent](http://delicious.com/help/api#posts_recent) call with whatever options you may want. That seems to work for me. Yahoo/Delicious doesn't throttle that request.

Comment: For posts/recent I get the same xml as given in the question.

Comment: So, making the call the way you are, the SSL cert can't be verified because it doesn't know where to get it. If you want it to be authenticated, you'll have to provide the Equifax root CA. If authentication isn't necessary, you can use the -k option like so:

curl -k -u username:password https://api.del.ic.ious/v1/posts/recent

Comment: Sorry, the post formated my url... it should be https :// api.del.ic.ious/v1/posts/recent